# Django Aggregation Question - Strange behavior

Tags: python, django, annotations, aggregate

I have a query set of activities which has an associated user_id on on that model. In this example, I have a query set containing the below based on this statement

```
activities.values('user_id').annotate(Min('duration'))

[
    {'user_id': 149026, 'duration__min': Decimal('480.0000')}, 
    {'user_id': 149026, 'duration__min': Decimal('454.0000')}, 
    {'user_id': 149026, 'duration__min': Decimal('360.0000')}, 
    {'user_id': 149027, 'duration__min': Decimal('420.0000')}
]
```

I need to grab the activity for each user_id that has the lowest duration. I'm a bit confused as to why the following statement below returns to me what I want

```
activities.values('user_id').annotate(Min('duration')).order_by('user_id')

[
    {'user_id': 149026, 'duration__min': Decimal('360.0000')}, 
    {'user_id': 149027, 'duration__min': Decimal('420.0000')}
]
```

Why would the order_by("user_id") clause return me the lowest duration activity for a specific user. Also, shouldn't the value clause preceding the annotate lead the returned query to have one annotated result for each unique user_id?

Comment: You can inspect the `.query` of the `QuerySet` so that you can understand what was the SQL query being *auto-generated* in each time

Comment: Exactly this case is described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by does it help? Do `activities` have any ordering (maybe in `Meta`)?

Comment: activities do not have any ordering in meta. i'll review and get back with q